# Syntactic analysis of the sentence

Tags: parsing

He lay still for a long time in the foreign softness of the bed, unable to figure out where he was.
Can you help me with this sentence?
I understand that still is certainly an adverb, but is ' for a long time' an adverb too or is it a prepositional phrase functioning as an adverbial modifier of time.
Is it a composite sentence or a compound? It seems to me that there are 2 clauses which are coordinated. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

> *He lay still for a long time in the foreign softness of the bed,*
> *unable to figure out where he was.*

"Still" is not an adverb here, but an adjective in predicative function; it describes the subject, cf. *He was still*.

It's an adverb in, for example, *I still love you*.

Yes: *for a long time* is a preposition phrase functioning as a time adjunct (your adverbial).

No: it's not a compound sentence (which consists of two or more linked main clauses) but a single main clause.

No: it's not a coordination of two clauses. The subordinate infinitival clause *to figure out where he was* is a dependent of the adjective "unable", not directly embedded within the main clause.

Comment: So, the clause '' unable to figure out where he was'' is certainly not an adverbial one as I thought, isn`t it?

Comment: @StudentStudent "Unable to figure out where he was" is not a clause. It's an adjective phrase headed by the adjective "unable" with the infinitival clause "to figure out where he was" as its complement. The phrase refers to the subject "he", cf. "He was unable to figure out where he was".

Comment: I am sorry to bother you once again. Does it mean that the '' unable to figure out where he was'' part functions as a predicative of a compound predicate in this sentence?

Comment: @StudentStudent Some people would say it is part of the predicate, but I prefer to analyse it as a supplement, a loosely attached expression that is not integrated into the structure of the clause but provides supplementary content.  It's usually set off by punctuation, as in your example, and by intonation.

Comment: Thank you for your help